# Causal question on a discrete signal

Tags: signal-analysis

Given a signal with a list of discrete values
1,2,3 (t=0),0,1,

Whether the signal is causal when the arrow is in 3 and why? I know the definition of causal is that the output will not depend on future input, but how to apply the definition in this question?

Comment: A _system_ is called causal if the system _output_ $y[n]$ at time $n$ does not depend at all on the input values $x[n+1], x[n+2], x[n+3], \cdots$ **all** of which are still in the future at time $n$.  A **signal** does not have an input or output and so it cannot be said to be causal.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I agree with you. Nevertheless it is quite common to speak of causal signals as defined [here](http://cnx.org/contents/7021a5b5-6cd9-4efc-92ed-2c77c8f204c4@3/Causal_Signals).

Comment: Thanks. I understand now by check the link which @DilipSarwate mentioned above.

Comment: @MattL.I have a following question. How did you use the theory which defines the system causal to explain the definition of causal function in the link? Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A signal x[n] is said to be causal if it could be the impulse response of a causal LTI system. That is, a signal is causal if x[n] = 0 when n < 0.

Comment: So the signal is h[n] = [4,0,1,0,2]
I was hoping someone can answer this question by doing z transform and then judging from ROC

Comment: If the signal is different from 0 for n < 0 then it isn't causal. It isn't necessary to calculate the z-transform. But the z-transform of a finite causal signal would not have terms with positive exponents in z (check the definition). Then the ROC of a finite duration causal signal would be the whole z-plane except for 0 (including infinity).